# How many different combinations of tense, mood and voice are there?

Tags: verb, conjugation

I'm attempting to list all of the different combinations of tenses, moods and aspects that can be derived from one verb. For example, you have all the indicatives then the indicatives with sein-passive then all the indicatives with werden-passive followed by subjunctives with the passives etc.. Does anyone have a definitive list and so can tell me how many structures can come from one verb?

Comment: You are looking for "forbidden" combinations?

Comment: @Janka No. All possible combinations :)

Comment: Please check https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/gehen.htm.

Comment: @Janka The problem I have with this is that it doesn't mention all the passive constructions etc..

Comment: It depends on how you count. Please be more specific about participles, infinitives, auxiliaries, persons, singular/plural. If you put all that into the mix, you end up with about 250 forms, but many of them are identical.

Comment: @Janka That's exactly what im looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Although I have not attempted to figure it out by counting, it seems that there cannot be a single answer. Not all verbs are valid or sensible in all forms. There are the statial and full passives, which you alluded to in the question, as well as the 3 moods of indicative, imperative, and subjunctive (2 forms, in German). Then there are the present, preterit, perfect, and future tenses. There is also [verb aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) which in German can be indicated/modified by prefixes with a huge array of combinations.

Linguistically your question is interesting, but from a learning stand point it won't get you far, or more likely, it will take you too far.

Answer (score 0):

Ich kann es leider nicht in vernünftigem Englisch sagen:

Wenn du wissen willst, welche Formen man mit einem Verb so alles bilden kann, ist **wiktionary.de** ein guter Startpunkt:
https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite

Wenn du dir dort ein Verb anzeigen lässt, erscheint rechts eine kleine Tabelle mit den wichtigsten Formen, aus denen sich die anderen Formen ableiten lassen. **Unten in der Tabelle gibt es einen Link** mit 'allen weitere Formen: Flexion: *dein.gesuchtes.Verb*'. Die Tabellen sind ziemlich vollständig; Formen, die nicht existieren, sind nicht aufgeführt. Das einzige, was fehlt, sind regionale oder bestimmte umgangssprachliche Formen wie doppeltes Perfekt/Plusquamperfekt, bekommen-Passiv usw.

Hier mal der Link zur Tabelle von '*öffnen*':

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:%C3%B6ffnen

Die Unzahl an Partikelverben (z.B. für 'gehen' mehr als 100: abgehen, angehen, aufgehen ...) sind dort aber längst noch nicht alle erfasst. Deren Formen lassen sich jedoch leicht aus 'Geschwisterverben'  herleiten.